# Losing Base table data after a region server dies

Tags: amazon-s3, hbase, emr, region

I have a issue with HBase cluster.

I have hosted an HBase cluster with Phoenix on EMR emr-5.8.0 and storage as S3. I have 1 master and 5 slaves 4.x large nodes. I’m losing the data while querying a table after a region server dies. I face this issue only if storage mode as S3, but with HDFS its working fine. Here are the steps I followed.

1. Launched the cluster with hfs replication factory as 3.
2. Created the tables and loaded the data using Phoenix.
3. Cross checked the data I loaded into tables and I see the data.
4. Wantedly terminated a EC2 machine which is part of cluster, meaning killing region server.
5. I could see EMR resizing and bringing up the new node.
6. When I query the table after the whole cluster is stable, which usually took 5-10 minutes, I see losing some data which is on dead RS.

I believe HBase replays the WAL once new node is brought up and I could also see the WAL file on HDFS new RS’s directory. But somehow I don’t see the complete data from the table.

Could you please let me know what possibly could go wrong. Also please let me know if I have to set any properties.

I would be happy to provide more details if you need.

Comment: Can you retry the same in latest emr-5.13.0 AMI?